Aligning cells to the top when using \SetCell for multiple rows

I want Row 1, 2, and 3 to be top aligned
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\sampleText}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, t] p{3.25cm}}, hlines, vlines, baseline=T, vspan=even, rowsep=0pt}
    
    Column 1
    & Column 2
    \\
    
    Row 1
    &
    \SetCell[r=3,c=1]{l}
    \sampleText
    \\
    
    Row 2
    &
    \\
     
    Row 3
    &
    \\
    
    Row 4
    & Short text
    \\
    
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


I think you could use h instead of t in colspec={Q[l, h] p{3.25cm}}:
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\sampleText}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, h] p{3.25cm}}, hlines, vlines, baseline=T, vspan=even, 
rowsep=0pt}
    Column 1
    & Column 2
    \\
    Row 1
    &
    \SetCell[r=3,c=1]{l}
    \sampleText
    \\
    Row 2
    &
    \\
    Row 3
    &
    \\
    Row 4
    & Short text
    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


